# How to check if div contains text (XPath)

Tags: xpath

I use https://autorefresh.io/expressions/ chrome extension for page refreshing. The next level for me is checking if a specific page part contains the predefined text. This extension supports XPath.
I was trying to use `//*[contains(text(),"Brak towaru")]`. It worked until I put this cell "address" instead of *.

```
/html/body[@class='b--desktop breakpoint-xl']/div[@class='body-inner']/
section[@class='pt-2']/div[@id='main']/div[@class='shop']/
div[@class='row mt-4 justify-content-center'][1]/div[@class='col-4 col-md-2 pt-3 text-center']
```

I was trying to insert this "address" in many ways... No success.

Any hints?

[screenshot of XPath extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMoY9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `contains(text())` try using `contains(.,)`. This will check for text content in the element itself and in it's child nodes.
So, instead of

```xml
//*[contains(text(),"Brak towaru")]
```

Try using

```xml
//*[contains(.,"Brak towaru")]
```

And in case this is a `div` element use

```xml
//div[contains(.,"Brak towaru")]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works :)
`//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[3][contains(.,"Brak towaru")]`

Comment: In case this resolved your problem please accept the answer to indicate the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Works :)
`//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[3][contains(.,"Brak towaru")]`